# "if" and "else if" commands are not working in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am in the process of making a chat bot and i am just experimenting at this point. but my "if" commands are not working and when i enter "moodToday" it just skips right to the else command.

(capitalization of "moodToday" is not the error)

any and all help would be appreciated

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

 int main() {

     char name[50], moodToday[50];


     cout << "A few things you should know at this time..." << endl << "1. I can't process last names." << endl << "2. I can't process acronyms." << endl;
     system("pause");
     cout << endl << endl << "What is your name?" << endl;
     cin >> name;
     cout << "Hello " << name << "." << endl << "How are you today?" << endl;
     cin >> moodToday;


     //can't figure this out...
     if ((moodToday == "sad") || (moodToday == "bad") || (moodToday == "horrible")) {
         cout << "That's not good." << endl << "Why are you feeling " << moodToday << "today?" << endl;
     }
     else if (moodToday == "good") {
         cout << "Great!" << endl;
     }
     else {
         cout << "I'm sorry, I don't undrestand that feeling." << endl;
     }


     system("pause");

     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: Important note: They're not "commands", they're flow control statements, or more generally, that's an `if` statement with an `else` clause.

Comment: Common guys ! 4 answers ! This proves that the question is good and interesting, even if the issue is not complex. Shouldn't this deserve a couple of upvotes ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing C++, then you should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and not the old C-style buffers.

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string name, moodToday;
}
```

C++ strings are significantly better than C strings since they don't have [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) problems and are easily compared with `==`.

Also, as a tip, try to avoid `using namespace std;` since that can cause namespace conflicts. As annoying as it can be to type `std::` all the time it does make it clear where that class or template originated from and who's responsible for it code-wise. That way your own classes and templates are obvious.

Answer (score 4):

To compare character arrays that contain strings you should use standard C functions like `std::strcmp` declared in header `<cstring>`. For example

```
#include <cstring>

//...

if ( std::strcmp( moodToday, "sad" ) == 0 ) std::cout << "They are equal << std::endl;
```

Otherwise in statements like this

```
if ((moodToday == "sad") ) /*...*/
```

there are compared two pointers: the pointer to the first character of the array `moodToday` and the pointer to the first character of the string literal `"sad"` because arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first characters.

Take into account that the usage of the `operator >>` with character arrays is unsafe

```
cin >> moodToday;
```

Use instead member function `getline`  like this

```
cin.getline( moodToday, sizeof( moodToday ) );
```

Or instead of the character arrays you could use standard class `std::string`.

Consider a ppossibility to convert all letters of the entered string to the case of the string literal before comparing them. You can do this using standard C functions `tolower` and `toupper` declared in header `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp` instead of `==` operators.

If you defined `moodToday` as a string object, then `==` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to problems in java with comparing object addresses what you are doing is comparing memory addresses. Thus you want to use strcmp(str1, "literal")==0 to see if they are equal.

```
#import <cstring>
if(strcmp(str1, "literal") == 0) dothis();
```

Comment: In C, yes. In C++, no.